# Invalid JSON error message in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net

I get 'Invalid JSON' error message when i run the below code in visual studio 2013, but if i copy the same code to visual studio 2010 it works fine. Here is the code :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawChartttt() {
            var test = window.location.href + "/test";

            var name = "sss";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.href + "/test",
                data: "{'name':'tman'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert("error 1");
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // alert("error 2");
                    alert(error);
                    alert(xhr);
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            drawChartttt();

        });

    </script>
```

Server side :

```
  [WebMethod]
     public static string test(string name)
      {
          return "tman";
      }
```

alert(status) displays parsererror

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Try passing your data like this:- `data:  JSON.stringify({"name" : "tman" }),`

Comment: @RahulSingh  i still get the same error message. With xhr.status 200

Comment: Okay you sure you are returning "tman", have you debugged or have you checked the browser console?

Comment: It does not trigger the server side webmethod at all. When i run it, it jumps to alert(error); section.

Comment: I've just noticed that this problem occurs if you select framework 4.5 when creating a new project. If i create 3.5 project and upgrade/change it to 4.5 i don't encounter this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91816/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-chosenone-thabs).